# calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really (FAILED - 1) ruby rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've asked this question before and maybe I wasn't clear enough (or didn't) put all the details of the my question.
It's been weeks now frustration is killing me on this assignment as I continue to switch sessions and the assignment itself seems enigmatic to everybody on Coursera since nobody has really answered the question in all the posts I've read.

[Here are the assignment questions](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxOTj_EJTdDGdTFsczNHTjJzYzg/view%20%22%20Here%20are%20the%20assignment%20questions)

 
Meanwhile this is my code:

```
#Implement all parts of this assignment within (this) module2_assignment2.rb file

#Implement a class called LineAnalyzer.
class LineAnalyzer
  #Implement the following read-only attributes in the LineAnalyzer class. 
  #* highest_wf_count - a number with maximum number of occurrences for a single word (calculated)
  #* highest_wf_words - an array of words with the maximum number of occurrences (calculated)
  #* content          - the string analyzed (provided)
  #* line_number      - the line number analyzed (provided)

  #Add the following methods in the LineAnalyzer class.
  #* initialize() - taking a line of text (content) and a line number
  #* calculate_word_frequency() - calculates result

  #Implement the initialize() method to:
  #* take in a line of text and line number
  #* initialize the content and line_number attributes
  #* call the calculate_word_frequency() method.

  #Implement the calculate_word_frequency() method to:
  #* calculate the maximum number of times a single word appears within
  #  provided content and store that in the highest_wf_count attribute.
  #* identify the words that were used the maximum number of times and
  #  store that in the highest_wf_words attribute.

    attr_accessor :highest_wf_count, :highest_wf_words, :content, :line_number


    def initialize(content, line)
    @content = content
    @line_number = line
    @highest_wf_count=0
    calculate_word_frequency()
  end

  def calculate_word_frequency()
    @highest_wf_words = Hash.new
    words = @content.split
    words.each { |w|
      if @highest_wf_words.has_key?(w)
        @highest_wf_words[w] += 1
      else
        @highest_wf_words[w] = 1
      end
    }
    @highest_wf_words.sort_by { |word, count| count }
    @highest_wf_words.each do |key, value|
      if value > @highest_wf_count
        @highest_wf_count = value
      end
    end
  end

  def highest_wf_count= (number)
    @highest_wf_count = number
  end

end


#  Implement a class called Solution. 
class Solution

  # Implement the following read-only attributes in the Solution class.
  #* analyzers - an array of LineAnalyzer objects for each line in the file
  #* highest_count_across_lines - a number with the maximum value for highest_wf_words attribute in the analyzers array.
  #* highest_count_words_across_lines - a filtered array of LineAnalyzer objects with the highest_wf_words attribute 
  #  equal to the highest_count_across_lines determined previously.

  # Implement the following methods in the Solution class.
  #* analyze_file() - processes 'test.txt' into an array of LineAnalyzers and stores them in analyzers.
  #* calculate_line_with_highest_frequency() - determines the highest_count_across_lines and 
  #  highest_count_words_across_lines attribute values  
  #* print_highest_word_frequency_across_lines() - prints the values of LineAnalyzer objects in 
  #  highest_count_words_across_lines in the specified format


  # Implement the analyze_file() method() to:
  #* Read the 'test.txt' file in lines 
  #* Create an array of LineAnalyzers for each line in the file

  # Implement the calculate_line_with_highest_frequency() method to:
  #* calculate the maximum value for highest_wf_count contained by the LineAnalyzer objects in analyzers array
  #  and stores this result in the highest_count_across_lines attribute.
  #* identifies the LineAnalyzer objects in the analyzers array that have highest_wf_count equal to highest_count_across_lines 
  #  attribute value determined previously and stores them in highest_count_words_across_lines.

  #Implement the print_highest_word_frequency_across_lines() method to
  #* print the values of objects in highest_count_words_across_lines in the specified format
  attr_reader  :analyzers, :highest_count_across_lines, :highest_count_words_across_lines

  def initialize()
    @analyzers = Array.new
    @highest_count_across_lines = nil
    @highest_count_words_across_lines = nil
  end

  def analyze_file()
    File.foreach('test.txt').with_index(1) do |content, line|
      line_analyzer = LineAnalyzer.new(content, line)
      @analyzers << line_analyzer
    end
  end

  def calculate_line_with_highest_frequency()
    @highest_count_across_lines = 0
    @highest_count_words_across_lines = Array.new
    @analyzers.each do |analyzer|
      if analyzer.highest_wf_count > @highest_count_across_lines
        @highest_count_across_lines = analyzer.highest_wf_count
      end
    end
  end

  def print_highest_word_frequency_across_lines()
    @highest_count_words_across_lines = Array.new
    puts "The following words have the highest word frequency per line:" 

  end
end
```

This is the rspec file for `class = solution`:

```
require_relative "../module2_assignment"
require 'rspec'

describe Solution do
  subject(:solution) { Solution.new }

  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:analyze_file) } 
  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:calculate_line_with_highest_frequency) } 
  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:print_highest_word_frequency_across_lines) } 

  context "#analyze_file" do
    it "creates 3 line analyzers" do
      expect(solution.analyzers.length).to eq 0 
      solution.analyze_file
      expect(solution.analyzers.length).to eq 3
    end  
  end

  context "#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency" do


    it "calculates highest count across lines to be 4" do
      solution.analyze_file

      expect(solution.highest_count_across_lines).to be nil

      solution.calculate_line_with_highest_frequency

      expect(solution.highest_count_across_lines).to be 4
    end  
    it "calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really" do
      solution.analyze_file

      expect(solution.highest_count_words_across_lines).to be nil

      solution.calculate_line_with_highest_frequency

      words_found = solution.highest_count_words_across_lines.map(&:highest_wf_words).flatten
      expect(words_found).to match_array ["will", "it", "really"] 
    end  
  end

end
```

The `test.txt` file:

```
This is a really really really cool experiment really
Cute little experiment
Will it work maybe it will work do you think it will it will
```

And this is the rspec results I've had so far:

```
LineAnalyzer
  has accessor for highest_wf_count
  has accessor for highest_wf_words
  has accessor for content
  has accessor for line_number
  has method calculate_word_frequency
  calls calculate_word_frequency when created
  attributes and values
    has attributes content and line_number
    content attribute should have value "test"
    line_number attribute should have value 1
  #calculate_word_frequency
    highest_wf_count value is 3
    highest_wf_words will include "really" and "you"
    content attribute will have value "This is a really really really cool cool you you you"
    line_number attribute will have value 2

Solution
  should respond to #analyze_file
  should respond to #calculate_line_with_highest_frequency
  should respond to #print_highest_word_frequency_across_lines
  #analyze_file
    creates 3 line analyzers
  #calculate_line_with_highest_frequency
    calculates highest count across lines to be 4
    calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really
     Failure/Error: expect(words_found).to match_array ["will", "it", "really"]

       expected collection contained:  ["it", "really", "will"]
       actual collection contained:    []
       the missing elements were:      ["it", "really", "will"]
     # ./spec/solution_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.13939 seconds (files took 0.39711 seconds to load)
19 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/solution_spec.rb:31 # Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really
```

I really can't figure out where the problem is.
Is it a typo problem or I'm doing something wrong somewhere?
If someone could help then it'll be very great,please.
Thanks in advance.
Brice

Comment: I just skimmed through the code... Without digging into what it's actually trying to do, I quickly noticed that you're **never putting anything in the `@highest_count_words_across_lines` array**!! You initialise it with `nil`, then set it to `Array.new`, then you never populate any values. So your final result is empty.

Comment: `[].map(&:highest_wf_words) == []`, and `[].flatten == []`. So since you never actually populate the array with any data, the rest of the code executes fine, but you still end up with an empty final result.

Comment: I tried doing this: @highest_count_words_across_lines = analyzer.highest_wf_words, to no avail.

Comment: Explicitly which line of code should I add and where? Can't figure out.

Comment: Implement the calculate_line_with_highest_frequency() method to: identifies the 'LineAnalyzer' objects in the 'analyzers' array that have 'highest_wf_count == highest_count_across_lines'  attribute value determined previously and store them in 'highest_count_words_across_lines'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said above, your immediate problem is that the `@highest_count_words_across_lines` is only ever set to an empty array - so the final result will inevitably also be empty.

You could build a list of all words containing the maximum number of repetitions as follows:

```
@highest_count_words_across_lines = analyzers.map do |analyzer|
  analyzer.highest_wf_words.select do |word, count|
    count == highest_count_across_lines
  end
end.flat_map(&:keys)
```

You may wish to move some of that logic into the `LineAnalyzer` class, e.g. in a `LineAnalyzer#words_of_length(length)` method.

Note that this will only return *two* values `["really", "it"]`. This is because your code is currently considering the first `"Will"` to be a different word as it is capitalised. If this is not desired, then you should `downcase` all words when analysing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much @Tom for your help. After some efforts the code below passed but not before applying the downcase at the LineAnalyser class level as you suggested:

```
 @highest_count_across_lines = analyzers.sort_by { |analyzer| analyzer.highest_wf_count }.reverse.first.highest_wf_count
    @highest_count_words_across_lines = analyzers.select { |analyzer| @highest_count_across_lines == analyzer.highest_wf_count  }
```

Many thanks again.

Comment: Sorry... To clarify, my demo code was to make `solution.highest_count_words_across_lines` the **answer**. You don't need to call any additional methods on it. Of course, if you wish to redesign the code to work in such a way, then go for it.

Comment: Also, this should not be submitted as an *answer*. Additional information like this should either be added as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47410424/edit) to your original post, or as a comment under mine.